# I have to wait few extra second before I can effectively send a message through contactform

Tags: php, xml, recaptcha

I made contact form that uses Google recaptcha(for spam-security) to sends messages to my email. Now when I fill all the field, check 'I am not a robot' box and then try to send message I don't receive any messages. But when I waited for 3-4 second and then send messages then I received message to my email address successfully. I also checked 'network' properties in 'inspect element' and all seems to work just fine. I also will provide code from my php.

I tried this in different browsers(including incognito mode) and devices, nothing helped or seemed to give hint for possible solution for this.

```
<?php

    $public_key = "MyPublicKey";
    $private_key = "MyPrivateKey"; 
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"; 


    /* Check if the form has been submitted */
    if(array_key_exists('submit_form',$_POST))
    {
        /* The response given by the form being submitted */
        $response_key = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        /* Send the data to the API for a response */
        $response = file_get_contents($url.'?secret='.$private_key.'&response='.$response_key.'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        /* json decode the response to an object */
        $response = json_decode($response);

        /* if success */
        if($response->success == 1)
        {   
        $name = $_POST['name'];
            $secret = $_POST['MyPrivateKey'];
            $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message']; 

            $check_list = "Package(s):  ".implode(" ", $_POST['check_list'])."\n";

            $formcontent="From: $name \n $check_list \n Message: $message";
            $recipient = "email@gmail.com";
            $mailheader = "Message from contact form: $email \r\n";
            mail($recipient, $email, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
            echo 'Mail sent!';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error, please try again!';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I guess the bad guy here is `file_get_contents` which you have to wait for - _But when I waited for 3-4 second..._ What do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Thanks for response! I try to explain it better. First example: I fill all the fields, check recaptcha box and wait til it's loaded and then submit my form but receive no message to my email. Second example: I fill all the fields, check recaptcha wait til it's loaded, but this time I wait 3-4 second before I submit my form and then I receive my message to my email.

Comment: Is there some other ajax functionality in your code which we don't see here?

Comment: @B001ᛦ No, this is all the php code that my website uses and there are no other ajax functionality used.